# how to set textures of another through script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a terrain generator system like Minecraft's and wanted to change the blocks textures, so I made a script, but textures are not set which make the blocks blank?

my script:

```
    private Vector3 position;
    private int chunkSize;
    private Material blockMaterial;
    public float noiseScale = 0.1f;
    public float amplitude = 5.0f;

    public void Initialize(Vector3 position, int chunkSize, Material blockMaterial)
    {
        

        this.position = position;
        this.chunkSize = chunkSize;
        this.blockMaterial = blockMaterial;
        GenerateTerrain();
    }

    void GenerateTerrain()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < chunkSize; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < chunkSize; z++)
            {
                float perlinValue = Mathf.PerlinNoise((x + position.x) * noiseScale, (z + position.z) * noiseScale);
                float y = perlinValue * amplitude; // Add randomness to terrain height

                for (int yBlock = 0; yBlock < y; yBlock++)
                {
                    Vector3 blockPosition = new Vector3(x, yBlock, z);
                    GameObject block = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
                    block.transform.parent = transform;
                    block.transform.position = blockPosition + position;

                    Block blockScript = block.AddComponent<Block>();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and the block script:

```
    public string blockType; // Name or identifier of the block
    public Texture grass;
    public Texture dirt;
    public Texture stone;

    void Start()
    {
        Renderer renderer = this.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        SetTextures();
    }

    void SetTextures()
    {
        float yPos = transform.position.y;

        if (yPos > 5)
        {
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = grass;
            blockType = "grass";
        }

        if (yPos <= 0)
        {
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = stone;
            blockType = "stone";
        }
        
        if (yPos > 0)
        {
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = dirt;
            blockType = "dirt";
        }
    }
```

I tried to use a cube prefab instead of a primitive cube but it was null and I tried writing the cube script in the chunk script but nothing happened... help please

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that your textures in `Block` script are not null.
2. If you want to use the default material that is used to draw primitives, make sure that you have light in your scene. It can be simple too dark without light you to be able to see changes.